# Multiple Items or Multiple Quanities in PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, paypal

**Updated for Shipping/Tax Help**

```
NSDecimalNumber *totalPriceNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[@(totalAmount) decimalValue]];
NSDecimalNumber *taxAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.07"];
NSDecimalNumber *shippingAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"20.00"];
NSDecimalNumber *subtotalAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.00"];


NSString *productFirst = [hiddenGloveIDOne text];
NSString *productSecond = [hiddenGloveIDTwo text];
NSString *productThird = [hiddenGloveIDThree text];
NSString *productFourth = [hiddenGloveIDFour text];

NSString *productCheckOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", productFirst, productSecond, productThird, productFourth];

self.resultText = nil;

PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.paymentDetails = [[PayPalPaymentDetails alloc] init];

payment.amount = totalPriceNumber;
payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
payment.shortDescription = productCheckOut;
payment.paymentDetails.subtotal = subtotalAmount;
payment.paymentDetails.shipping = shippingAmount;
payment.paymentDetails.tax = taxAmount;
```

Does anyone have any experience with PayPal iOS SDK sources?

Right now I am trying to add multiple products to a price total. I have seen that this has not been an allowed in later iOS SDK's. Anyone know if this has been updated to allow this yet?

If this has not. Is it possible to have one individual product but allow the price to multiplied a quantity?

So what happens in this app is you select a medical glove - then a size - then a quantity. The total then needs to be calculated.

Here is a link to the project on github https://github.com/BG-Designs/MedExpress-Glove-App

Any help or advice that I could get this work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*UPDATED***

```
- (IBAction)pay{

NSString *priceStringOne = [hiddenPriceOneTF text];

float priceFloatOne = [priceStringOne floatValue];

NSString *priceStringTwo = [hiddenPriceTwoTF text];

float priceFloatTwo = [priceStringTwo floatValue];

NSString *priceStringThree = [hiddenPriceThreeTF text];

float priceFloatThree = [priceStringThree floatValue];

NSString *priceStringFour = [hiddenPriceFourTF text];

float priceFloatFour = [priceStringFour floatValue];

NSString *quanityStringOne = [quanityFirstTF text];

float quanityFloatOne = [quanityStringOne floatValue];

NSString *quanityStringTwo = [quanitySecondTF text];

float quanityFloatTwo = [quanityStringTwo floatValue];

NSString *quanityStringThree = [quanityThirdTF text];

float quanityFloatThree = [quanityStringThree floatValue];

NSString *quanityStringFour = [quanityFourthTF text];

float quanityFloatFour = [quanityStringFour floatValue];

float totalAmount = priceFloatOne * quanityFloatOne + priceFloatTwo * quanityFloatTwo + priceFloatThree * quanityFloatThree + priceFloatFour * quanityFloatFour ;

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" $ %0.2f", totalAmount];

[totalPriceCalculated setText:result];

// Remove our last completed payment, just for demo purposes.
self.completedPayment = nil;

PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", totalPriceCalculated.text]];
payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
payment.shortDescription = @"Hipster t-shirt";

if (!payment.processable) {
    // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
    // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
    // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
    // to handle that here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@user3014076, the PayPal iOS SDK currently supports only a single, total, amount per payment. You will need to do the additions and multiplications in your app, and then submit only the final result to the SDK.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the response. I am not sure if you have looked at the GitHub file but I have attempted to that. Now I don't know if I went the right route to do this. But I did try this. Added some code from that section above.

Comment: @user3014076 that code looks basically correct to me, at a quick glance. Are you running into a problem?

Comment: yeah the payment.amount string is blank for me. But if I do the normal string [NSDecimal Number inItWithString = @"5.69"] (i think off the top of my head) then 5.69 will show up. So its like not understanding the calculation thats being done with all those strings/text fields.

I would like to add images but don't have the reputation too.

Comment: @user3014076 I'm happy to help with issues involving the PayPal iOS SDK. But it sounds like your remaining problem actually involves converting your `totalPriceCalculated` object (whose class I don't know) into a `NSDecimalNumber`. This is a general Objective C issue, not a PayPal iOS SDK issue.

Comment: Hey Dave, Noobish question for you, how do you apply the new "tax" and "shipping," to the view controller? Any tutorials online to help out?

Comment: Bryan, something like this: `payment.paymentDetails = [[PayPalPaymentDetails alloc] init]; payment.paymentDetails.shipping = shippingAmount; payment.paymentDetails.tax = taxAmount;`

Comment: Hey Dave, I have attempted this and I am getting no errors, but nothing is happening. Updated above to show what i have now. Does this need to be live to work?

Comment: By "nothing is happening" do you mean that when your server fetches the payment information, these details are not showing? If so, I'm not sure what the problem would be. Hmm. It probably couldn't hurt to also set the remaining detail, `subtotal`, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: correct, it just goes through the normal process like i didn't even have shipping or tax added in as code. Added subtotal and still having the same problem.

Should the `subtotal` be my products price and the `payment.amount` be the shipping,taxes, and subtotal combined?

Comment: Bryan, if you look in your app's Console Log, are there really no errors returned? In any case, be sure that `payment.amount = payment.paymentDetails.subtotal + payment.paymentDetails.shipping + payment.paymentDetails.tax`.

Comment: I had no errors when I had the `payment.amount = totalPriceNumber` Now that I have tried your above code I am getting the error _Invalid operands to binary expression('NSDecimalNumber*' and 'NSDecimalNumber*')_ . I looked this up and looks like its having issues adding NSDecimalNumbers, Is this correct? All this stuff is going straight over my head today and I am completely lost.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, Bryan! I should have written `payment.amount == ...` rather than `payment.amount = ...`! In other words, I was just trying to say that you need to be sure that the sum of the three detail values equals the payment's `amount` value.

Comment: Hey Dave, Still kinda struggling with this and have left it alone for awhile, just curious could you explain what exactly shipping and tax add to the new SDK. Is it essentially just adding a string to the total? And nothing else? or Is it actually showing these amounts when checking out? What about does it allow the user to add their shipping place?  If you have images to show those would work, Im more of a visual person. Thanks!

Comment: Bryan, at this point those amounts are for your own bookkeeping. When your server obtains the payment details from PayPal's servers (or when you check your dashboard in the Developer Portal), those amounts will be broken out just as you provided them. In the future we might also break them out in the mSDK display where the user is asked to send their payment.

Comment: So what it sounds like is I don't "really" need these, if i was able to add them into an NSSTRING like i have with the other totals? Correct me if I am wrong though. I also remember you answering a question of someone that needed to add the customers address, and i think you said that this needed to be added on its own. Could you point me in the right direction on this so it sends with the payment? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Bryan: as far as the SDK is concerned, you don't need to provide the payment details. Re passing an arbitrary string into the SDK so that it comes out at the other end of the payment for use by your server, this is not currently supported.